# DocuSignAPI - Port 443 is not available

Tags: docusignapi

I have a DocuSign integration with Laserfiche that I'm trying to configure. The networking IT team cannot use port 443 for incoming documents (it's being used by another service). How can I configure another port to be used?
The issue being that the small business this will be for does not have many external IP addresses and they run Exchange which also requires port 443. So to utilize DocuSign, a second IP address would need to be used just for this small implementation.
Does every installation of a DocuSign integration use 443? There is NOBODY out there who has run into a similar issue and wanted to utilize a different port?

Answer (score 1):

Please reach out to DocuSign support and/or any DocuSign integrator partner you have been in contact with for this topic.

Comment: I reached out to the DocuSign tech team and they directed me here because it was "out of their scope of knowledge."